# how can we pass PHP variable value as argument|param within ng-click() direcive in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

how can we pass PHP variable value as argument|param within ng-click() direcive in angularjs?

In the below example I want to pass 1 as argument by using ng-click directive of angularjs

Example:

```
$uu="1";
ng-click('<?=$uu?>')
```

Comment: Just do it ng-click('1')?  ng-click('$uu')

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:
http://angularretentive.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/passing-your-php-variables-to-angular.html

Or this one:
http://angularretentive.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/passing-your-php-variables-to-angular.html?showComment=1395883898464#c7317872000815324734

Looks like it might help you with getting your PHP variable into angularjs context.