# Passing SESSION variable into angularjs textbox value

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to pass the `userID` from the session to the AngularJS textbox value? I have tried to put the echo call into the `value=""` but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="user" id="user" 
       value="<?php echo $user; ?>" disabled/> 
<button data-ng-click="add(userID)">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use php variable in angular template. As this template is render by angular engine so it will interpolate only scope variables. Use services for your data to get it from php and use it through your controller.

Ref - [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214238/how-can-we-pass-php-variable-value-as-argumentparam-within-ng-click-direcive)

Comment: not working sir. this error come out Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character